# Scale div to the height of background-image

Tags: css, responsive

I am trying to put the image as a background image and some text on a Background. The problem is: the height of div has to be the same as the background image height.

**HTML**

```
<div class="pict-cont">
    <div class="text">enter code here`
        <p style="color: #333">some text some text some text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pict-cont {   
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/ba/Dresdner_Elblforenz_bei_D%C3%A4mmerung%2C_2008.jpg/330px-Dresdner_Elblforenz_bei_D%C3%A4mmerung%2C_2008.jpg');
    background-color: #333;
    height: 1024px;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/innpe/4b7bc2y6/1/

Comment: Is JavaScript an option?

Comment: I am looking for an option. Could be JavaScript too.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this class:

```
.text {
  border: solid;
  height: 100%;
}
```

This way the div has same height as the background image div. You can resize the image div to your need.

If you want the image to fill that div, use

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Yes, i want the image to fill that div, but i need it in responsive version. "Background-size: cover" doesn't works if i change a window size.

Comment: Leave it `cover` and then make responsive only the div that contains the image.